# How to Get Azure Windows VM plan info?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-powershell

I'm looking for powershell command to get an Azure Windows VM plan info. I looked up [Get-AzVM](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.compute/get-azvm?view=azps-5.8.0), but unable to find the required info.

Here's the property on azure portal, that I'm looking for

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Please find the below screenshot to get the vm plan information

CLI

```
az vm show --name myvm  --resource-group test --query storageProfile.imageReference.sku
```

[image]
[image]

Powershell

```
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName test -Name myvm -Status | select OsName
```

[image]

To get the status of all vms in the resource group :

```
Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName test -Status
```

[image]

If this solve your problem then mark this your answer

Comment: Thanks @Rahul Shukla, I was looking your Powershell approach rather than CLI. I tried it, but seems like it works only if the VM is running. How to get when VM's are stopped? I had a task to get all the windows servers of 2016 from a RG which may contain stopped instances too.

Comment: @Zarak1 Updated the answer ,Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName test -Status
 gives the status of the all vms in the given resource group

Answer (score 1):

Use the below query:

```
az vm show --name myvm  --resource-group test --query storageProfile.imageReference.sku
```